# Which is better in shell scripting, whether to export a variable in a function call or return using echo in the function call?

Tags: shell, sh

Export the variable in function

```
func() {  
    export $1=10  
}  
func param  
echo $param
```

Echo the variable in function

```
func() {  
    var=$1  
    var=10  
    echo "$var"  
}  

var=$( func param  )
echo $var
```

Comment: If you are using actual functions, you may as well use the return value from them, though this is highly contextual and may even be based on opinion. Not sure this actually answerable in the current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is preferable because it doesn't involve starting a separate process to produce the value. That said, you don't need to use `export`, because you don't particularly need to export the value. You just need a global variable. Use `printf` to assign to a variable whose name is passed as an argument.

```
func () {
    printf -v "$1" '10'
}
```

Note that in your second attempt, the argument isn't actually used. What you wrote is equivalent to

```
func () {
    echo 10
}

var=$(func)
```